# Somebody who own MSP432P401R User Guide?

Tags: microcontroller, texas-instruments, documentation

Is there somebody, who can deliver me the **user guide** for **MSP432P401R**? I know, this question looks dummy. However the mentioned part **lost support** from the side of Texas Instruments, and they cannot send me the user guide.

**I spent a lot of time finding the document on the web.**

I will be so pleased if is here somebody who has saved this document and can share it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're looking for a forum. This is a Q&A.

Comment: This: https://datasheet.octopart.com/MSP-EXP432P401R-Texas-Instruments-datasheet-39145419.pdf ? Took less than a minute... with some tricks though. Or a datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slas826e/slas826e.pdf

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you for your link. However, it is not what I am finding.
In the header of your document is the User's Guide. However, that does not contain information about the registers of peripheries Timer, ADC, etc. 
I am looking for similar like is this: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf

Comment: There is a Technical Reference. Seems comprehensive: https://academics.uccs.edu/mlaubhan/common/MSP432/slau356e.pdf

Comment: Oh, thank you so much.
This is what I need. Thank you again and have a nice day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct name of this document is "MSP432P4xx SimpleLink™ Microcontrollers Technical Reference Manual". Its identifier is SLAU356.

It is, of course, available on archive.org:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200601174233/http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau356i/slau356i.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much for the web.archive link and for correcting the name of the document.

Comment: The TRM is for the whole MSP432 family. You also need the datasheet for the particular device you are using.